# How do I import the list of files from a Google Folder into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory

I have been asked to pull in a list of file names and urls from a Google folder to a Google Spreadsheet. I've tried applying a script but I'm not sure what to do.

Can you help?

Comment: select edit -> edit by google doc

Comment: you want to pull *a list* of files (names and links for ex.) and insert them into a google spreadsheet? in that case show where you are at so far.

Comment: I think I should have used the word "'Extract' from a Google Folder to a Google Sheet" not 'Import'. I want to extract all the documents in a folder (whatever file type) and import them into a Google Sheet

Comment: extract makes even less sense to me in this context

Comment: OK, the full description of the issue is this: in Google Drive, when one uploads a document, they get put into a folder. So let's say ten samples of a student's work have been uploaded to a folder. In this case the teacher wants to click on a Google Sheet (spreadsheet) and for the contents of the student folder to be extracted from the folder and itemised line by line to the spreadsheet. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

No work shown but ok. This will give you a list of filenames and their urls:

```js
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

/*
The ONLY WAY to get the Id  of a folder by right-clicking it and inspecting the link
Example: link= 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw34txsxdsVDeuacnV2t0VHg1eGM&authuser=0'
the id = '0Bw34txsxdsVDeuacnV2t0VHg1eGM'
DOUBLE CHECK YOUR ID!
*/
function getFileArray(folderId){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var fileList = [];
  
  //Loop though files and add names and urls to the array
  while (files.hasNext()){ 
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();    
    var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    fileList = fileList.concat([[fileName, fileUrl]]);
  }
   //See returned fileList in a log
  //Logger.log( fileList ) //Preview Returned Array      
  return fileList
  
 
}

  
//Prints any 2D array to a range that starts with the selected cell
function printArrayToSelection(twoDimArr){  
  var firstCell = SS.getActiveCell();
  var lastCell = firstCell.offset(twoDimArr.length - 1, twoDimArr[0].length - 1);
  var destinationRange = SS.getActiveSheet().getRange(
    firstCell.getA1Notation() + ':' + lastCell.getA1Notation());
  destinationRange.setValues(twoDimArr);
  
}

//Print the actual data
function printFileArray(){
  printArrayToSelection(getFileArray('yourforderid'));
}
```

Comment: That's hugely appreciated. Can I ask for more help to implement it. I am inexperienced and I don't know how to apply the code you have provided. Do I use the script editor? Do I have to edit the code to reference a particular folder? How do I run it in Google Drive? Jonny

Comment: you need to put your 'folderID' into the printFileArray function. Then run printFileArray().

Comment: you need to call the script editor from the spreadsheet ->  paste the code into it. Please search google first if you get stuck.

Comment: +1 for patience! PS: generating a log AFTER a return statement will leave you wondering where the log went...